# What does the distance in machine learning signify?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, classification

In Neural networks, we regularly use the equation:

```
w1*x1 + w2*x2 + w3*x3 ...
```

We can interpret this as equation of a line with each x as a dimension. To make things more clearer, lets take an example of a simple perceptron network.

Imagine a single layer perceptron with 2 ip's/features (x1 & x2) and one output (y). (Sorry stackoverflow didn't allow me to post an additional image)

```
Let
R = w1*x1 + w2 * x2
y = 0 if R >= threshold
y = 1 if R < threshold
```

**Scenario 1**:

```
Threshold = 0 
w1 = 2, w2 = -1
```

The line separating class 0 and 1 has the equation 2*x1 - x2 = 0

[image: Figure 1]

Suppose we get a test sample

```
P = (1,1)
R = 2*1 - 1 = 1 > 0
```

Sample P belongs to class 1

**My questions is what is this R?**

From the figure, its horizontal distance from the line.

**Scenario 2**:

```
Threshold = 0
w1 = 2, w2 = 1
```

The line separating class 0 and 1 has the equation 2*x1 + x2 = 0

[image: Figure 2]

P = (1,1) 
R = 2*1 + 1 = 3 > 0 
Sample P belongs to class 1

From the figure, its vertical distance from the line.

R is supposed to mean some form of distance from the classifying line. More the distance, more farther away from the line and we are more confident about the classification.
Just want to know what kind of distance from the line is R?

Comment: "In Machine learning, we always have an equation" Why think that? The possession of an equation is not a defining feature of machine learning. In any event, there are all sorts of notions of distance used in mathematics and computer science. In machine learning it is typically some sort of measure of distance to a solution.

Comment: I'd move this question to http://math.stackexchange.com/. It's maths, not programming.

Comment: But I don't think there is a good answer. R is not a metric in the sense that it doesn't satisfy the triangle inequality, and it allows negative values, which distances don't. You could think of it as a 'level' more than a distance: the total input level?